# Icons do not work when implementing AdminLTE theme in JSF project

Tags: css, jsf, icons, xhtml, adminlte

I am trying to implement AdminLTE theme in my project. I am an intern and working with jsf+hibernate. I have been told to use adminlte theme and trying to work it out with jsf.

At the beginning I fixed the stylesheeet syntax and JS syntax. After that fixed the `/>` parts of the code to apply on JSF. Now everything is looking same except icons. I am trying to implement them same way as I implemented JS and CSS files but it does not work.

For example, code was:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/adminlte.min.css">
```

and I am using it like:

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="dist/css" name="adminlte.min.css" />
```

It works when I'm use:

```
<h:graphicImage name ="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8"/>
```

instead of:

```
<img src="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8"/>
```

Icons look like this: [image: icons image]

My `template.xhtml`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
This is a starter template page. Use this page to start your new project from
scratch. This page gets rid of all links and provides the needed markup only.
-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
  <title>AdminLTE 3 | Starter</title>

  <!-- Google Font: Source Sans Pro -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,400i,700&amp;display=fallback"/>
  <h:outputStylesheet library="plugins/fontawesome-free/css" name="all.min.css" />
  <h:outputStylesheet library="dist/css" name="adminlte.min.css" />
</h:head>
<h:body class="hold-transition sidebar-mini">
<div class="wrapper">

  <!-- Navbar -->
  <nav class="main-header navbar navbar-expand navbar-white navbar-light">
    <!-- Left navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="pushmenu" href="#" role="button"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="index3.html" class="nav-link">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item d-none d-sm-inline-block">
        <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Right navbar links -->
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <!-- Navbar Search -->
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="navbar-search" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
        <div class="navbar-search-block">
          <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
              <input class="form-control form-control-navbar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="submit">
                  <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-navbar" type="button" data-widget="navbar-search">
                  <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </li>

      <!-- Messages Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="far fa-comments"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-danger navbar-badge">3</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
                <h:graphicImage name ="dist/img/user1-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle"/>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  Brad Diesel
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-danger"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">Call me whenever you can...</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
                <h:graphicImage name ="dist/img/user8-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3"/>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  John Pierce
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-muted"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">I got your message bro</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <!-- Message Start -->
            <div class="media">
                <h:graphicImage name ="dist/img/user3-128x128.jpg" alt="User Avatar" class="img-size-50 img-circle mr-3"/>
              <div class="media-body">
                <h3 class="dropdown-item-title">
                  Nora Silvester
                  <span class="float-right text-sm text-warning"><i class="fas fa-star"></i></span>
                </h3>
                <p class="text-sm">The subject goes here</p>
                <p class="text-sm text-muted"><i class="far fa-clock mr-1"></i> 4 Hours Ago</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Message End -->
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Messages</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <!-- Notifications Dropdown Menu -->
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          <i class="far fa-bell"></i>
          <span class="badge badge-warning navbar-badge">15</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
          <span class="dropdown-header">15 Notifications</span>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-envelope mr-2"></i> 4 new messages
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">3 mins</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-users mr-2"></i> 8 friend requests
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">12 hours</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">
            <i class="fas fa-file mr-2"></i> 3 new reports
            <span class="float-right text-muted text-sm">2 days</span>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-item dropdown-footer">See All Notifications</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="fullscreen" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fas fa-expand-arrows-alt"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" data-widget="control-sidebar" data-slide="true" href="#" role="button">
          <i class="fas fa-th-large"></i>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <!-- /.navbar -->

  <!-- Main Sidebar Container -->
  <aside class="main-sidebar sidebar-dark-primary elevation-4">
    <!-- Brand Logo -->
    <a href="index3.html" class="brand-link">
        <h:graphicImage name="dist/img/AdminLTELogo.png" alt="AdminLTE Logo" class="brand-image img-circle elevation-3" style="opacity: .8"/>
      <span class="brand-text font-weight-light">PM System</span>
    </a>

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <div class="sidebar">
      <!-- Sidebar user panel (optional) -->
      <div class="user-panel mt-3 pb-3 mb-3 d-flex">
        <div class="image">
            <h:graphicImage name ="dist/img/user2-160x160.jpg" class="img-circle elevation-2" alt="User Image"/>
        </div>
        <div class="info">
          <a href="#" class="d-block">Kullanıcı Adı</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- SidebarSearch Form -->
      <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="input-group" data-widget="sidebar-search">
          <input class="form-control form-control-sidebar" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
          <div class="input-group-append">
            <button class="btn btn-sidebar">
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-fw"></i>
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Sidebar Menu -->
      <nav class="mt-2">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-sidebar flex-column" data-widget="treeview" role="menu" data-accordion="false">
          <!-- Add icons to the links using the .nav-icon class
               with font-awesome or any other icon font library -->
          <li class="nav-item menu-open">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
              <p>
                Starter Pages
                <i class="right fas fa-angle-left"></i>
              </p>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav nav-treeview">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Active Page</p>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                  <i class="far fa-circle nav-icon"></i>
                  <p>Inactive Page</p>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
              <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
              <p>
                Simple Link
                <span class="right badge badge-danger">New</span>
              </p>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <!-- /.sidebar-menu -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.sidebar -->
  </aside>

  <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
  <div class="content-wrapper">
    <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
    <div class="content-header">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row mb-2">
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0">Starter Page</h1>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
              <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
              <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Starter Page</li>
            </ol>
          </div><!-- /.col -->
        </div><!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content-header -->

    <!-- Main content -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                  content.
                </p>

                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>

                <p class="card-text">
                  Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's
                  content.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
                <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.card -->
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
          <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h6>

                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="card card-primary card-outline">
              <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="m-0">Featured</h5>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <h6 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h6>

                <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.content-wrapper -->

  <!-- Control Sidebar -->
  <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
    <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
    <div class="p-3">
      <h5>Title</h5>
      <p>Sidebar content</p>
    </div>
  </aside>
  <!-- /.control-sidebar -->

  <!-- Main Footer -->
  <footer class="main-footer">
    <!-- To the right -->
    <div class="float-right d-none d-sm-inline">
      Anything you want
    </div>
    <!-- Default to the left -->
    <strong>Copyright &amp;copy; 2014-2021 <a href="https://adminlte.io">AdminLTE.io</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
  </footer>
</div>
<!-- ./wrapper -->

<!-- REQUIRED SCRIPTS -->

        <h:outputScript library="plugins/jquery" name="jquery.min.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="plugins/bootstrap/js" name="bootstrap.bundle.min.js"/>
        <h:outputScript library="dist/js" name="adminlte.min.js"/>

</h:body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try font awsome like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-9usAa10IRO0HhonpyAIVpjrylPvoDwiPUiKdWk5t3PyolY1cOd4DSE0Ga+ri4AuTroPR5aQvXU9xC6qOPnzFeg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
```